# Freeze selected item when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a requirement, where I need to freeze the selected item from list of items in a container to top, when the selected item is in top fold of the container. and when the selected item is in bottom fold of the container, I need to stick it to the bottom.

If the selected item is in visible fold, nothing should happen. I mean the selected item should be in normal flow with other adjacent items.

I somehow managed to solve this to some extent. But when I scroll up, when the selected item is sticked above of the container, the selected item is hiding. This behavior is happening even when I scroll down, when the selected item is sticked to the bottom of the container.

[**Here is the Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/fmjyttgh/6/)

[image]

```
$('.item').click(function () {
    $('.item').removeClass('select').removeClass('pAbsolute');
    $(this).addClass('select');
});

$('.parent').scroll(function () {
    var $selected = $('.item.select');
    var cTop = $selected.offset().top;
    var cHeight = $selected.height();
    var pHeight = $(this).height();
    if (cTop < 0) {
        $selected.css({
            'top': $(this).scrollTop(),
                'bottom': ''
        }).addClass('pAbsolute');
    } else if (cTop > pHeight - cHeight) {
        $selected.css({
            'bottom': -$(this).scrollTop(),
                'top': ''
        }).addClass('pAbsolute');
    } else {
        $selected.css({
            'top': '',
                'bottom': ''
        }).removeClass('pAbsolute');
    }
});
```

Comment: How many selected items can you have? Your fiddle shows two elements that are "selected" (1 and 22).

Comment: @JackPattishall only one at a time. **I updated the fiddle** (_it was a bug_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses a bottom and top header who are filled in with the selected values and showed/hidden when necessary:

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmjyttgh/27/)**

Javascript:

```
function stickItems($parent, itemClass, selectClass) {
    // Attach dummy element items
    $parent.prepend('<div class="' + itemClass + ' sticky top"></div>');
    $parent.append('<div class="' + itemClass + ' sticky bottom"></div>');

    var $items = $('.' + itemClass),
        $stickyTop = $('.' + itemClass + '.sticky.top'),
        $stickyBottom = $('.' + itemClass + '.sticky.bottom');

    // Click event registering 
    $items.click(function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).hasClass('sticky')) {
            $items.removeClass(selectClass);
            $stickyTop.css('display', 'none');
            $stickyBottom.css('display', 'none');
            $(this).addClass(selectClass);
        }
    });



    // Scroll event
    $parent.scroll(function () {
        var $self = $(this);
        var $selected = $('.' + itemClass + '.' + selectClass);
        var cTop = $selected.offset().top;
        var pTop = $self.offset().top;
        var cHeight = $selected.height();
        var pHeight = $self.height();
        if (cTop - pTop <= 0) {
            $stickyTop.html($selected.html()).css({
                'display': 'block',
                    'top': $(this).scrollTop()
            });
            $stickyBottom.css('display', 'none');
        } else if (cTop > pTop && cTop < pTop + pHeight) {
            $stickyTop.css('display', 'none');
            $stickyBottom.css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            $stickyTop.css('display', 'none');
            $stickyBottom.html($selected.html()).css({
                'display': 'block',
                    'bottom': -$(this).scrollTop()
            });
        }
    });
}

stickItems($('.parent'), 'item', 'select');
```

Css:

```
body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    padding-top: 200px;
}
.parent {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.item {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: tomato;
}
.item.select {
    background-color: beige;
}
.item.sticky {
    background-color: beige;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="item sticky top"></div>
    <div class="item select">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <!-- ... -->
    <div class="item">39</div>
    <div class="item">40</div>
    <div class="item">41</div>
    <div class="item sticky bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Salute to your thought :)

Comment: This solution works fine but if there is a gap on top of the container, I can see two selected items with same content. please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/fmjyttgh/24/). I modified the code but not the concept.

Comment: I solved it. Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/fmjyttgh/26/). If you don't mind, I will update your post. (_rollback if you don't like it_)

Comment: Good job! Sorry but I had no further time to look into it right now.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a consistent value to keep the initial offset relative to the container when you select it.

Then, calculate the offset and scroll value,

1. If cTop < 0, which means its top out of box, stick to top.
2. If cTop + cHeight > pHeight, which means its view is out of bottom block, set to bottom.
3. Else stay in position.

Edit:

When selecting a new Item, as the previous item may have `.pAbsolute` attr, the relative position of current item may change, but we can get the offset change by track the offset before and after those class add/remove actions.

Then we can add the missing height by change the scrollTop of the container manually.

```js
var offset;
$('.item').click(function () {
    // This is the offset in container before class change.
    offset = this.offsetTop;
    $('.item').removeClass('select').removeClass('pAbsolute');
    $(this).addClass('select');
    // Calculate the difference
    var distortion = offset - this.offsetTop;
    
    // Remove the distortion by manual scroll.
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.scrollTop($parent.scrollTop() - distortion);
    
    offset = this.offsetTop;
});


$('.parent').scroll(function () {
    var $selected = $('.item.select');
    var cTop = offset - $(this).scrollTop();
    var cHeight = $selected.height();
    var pHeight = $(this).height();
    if (cTop < 0) {
        $selected.css({
            'top': $(this).scrollTop(),
                'bottom': ''
        }).addClass('pAbsolute');
    } else if (cTop + cHeight > pHeight) {
        $selected.css({
            'bottom': -$(this).scrollTop(),
                'top': ''
        }).addClass('pAbsolute');
    } else {
        $selected.css({
            'top': '',
                'bottom': ''
        }).removeClass('pAbsolute');
    }
});
```

```css
body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.parent {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.item {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: tomato;
    width: 100%;
}
.item.select {
    background-color: beige;
}
.pAbsolute {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="item select">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
    <div class="item">11</div>
    <div class="item">12</div>
    <div class="item">13</div>
    <div class="item">14</div>
    <div class="item">15</div>
    <div class="item">16</div>
    <div class="item">17</div>
    <div class="item">18</div>
    <div class="item">19</div>
    <div class="item">20</div>
    <div class="item">21</div>
    <div class="item">22</div>
    <div class="item">23</div>
    <div class="item">24</div>
    <div class="item">25</div>
    <div class="item">26</div>
    <div class="item">27</div>
    <div class="item">28</div>
    <div class="item">29</div>
    <div class="item">30</div>
    <div class="item">31</div>
    <div class="item">32</div>
    <div class="item">33</div>
    <div class="item">34</div>
    <div class="item">35</div>
    <div class="item">36</div>
    <div class="item">37</div>
    <div class="item">38</div>
    <div class="item">39</div>
    <div class="item">40</div>
    <div class="item">41</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is actually working a bit more than what I have shown above. There are still some issues like: when I click a item, the item's position is shifting. That will definitely confuse the user. I will try here to fix it too. again, thanks for this. :)

Comment: I think we need to wrap each item in a wrapper to hold the height. but in my case, I can't do so because the heights are not fixed.

Comment: I got some idea, trying on jsfiddle.